# Thymeleaf table - send id from selected row with form-tag

Tags: forms, thymeleaf

I'm very new to thymeleaf. I have a table with multiple rows and try to send an id to my rest-server.

```
                <tr th:each="teilnahmeForm : ${teilnahmeFormList}">
                    <td th:utext="${teilnahmeForm.kongressBezeichung}"></td>
                    <td><a th:href="@{/user/editAbstract(teilnahmeId=${teilnahmeForm.id})}">Bearbeiten</a></td>
                    <!--<td><a th:href="@{/user/editFile(teilnahmeId=${teilnahmeForm.id})}">Bearbeiten</a></td>-->
                    <td>
                        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/user/uploadFile">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="file" name="file"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

This is my restserver:

```
    @GetMapping("/user/uploadFile")
public ModelAndView handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
                                     , int teilnahmeID          
) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(); 
.... 
return modelAndView;}
```

How can i send the id from the row, i select to upload my file, to my rest-server-method?

Answer (score 0):

```
          <tr th:each="teilnahmeForm : ${teilnahmeFormList}">
                <td th:utext="${teilnahmeForm.kongressBezeichung}"></td>
                <td><a th:href="@{/user/editAbstract(teilnahmeId=${teilnahmeForm.id})}">Bearbeiten</a></td>
                <!--<td><a th:href="@{/user/editFile(teilnahmeId=${teilnahmeForm.id})}">Bearbeiten</a></td>-->
                <td>
                    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/user/uploadFile">
      <input type="hidden" name="teilnahmeID" th:value="${teilnahmeForm.id}" />   <!-- add this line -->
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="file" name="file"/></td>
                                <td><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
```